# What is the conditiones to have the plane $(ABC) $ and $(DEF) $ perpendicular?

Tags: geometry

Let $A(a_1, a_2, a_3),  B(b_1, b_2, b_3),  C(c_1, c_2, c_3), D(d_1, d_2, d_3), E(e_1, e_2, e_3), F(f_1, f_2, f_3)$ in the 3d system of coordinates.

What is the conditiones to have the plane $(ABC) $ and $(DEF) $ perpendicular?

Comment: Where does this come from and what are your own thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise different and that the same holds for $D$, $E$ and $F$ (otherwise the question is meaningless).

We have that
$$(ABC)\perp (DEF)\iff \textbf{u}\perp \textbf{v}\iff \textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{v}=0$$

Where $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are non-zero vectors normal to $(ABC)$ and $(DEF)$ respectively. Moreover you should convince yourself that
$$\textbf{u}\perp (ABC)\iff \textbf{u}\perp (AB)\text{ and }\textbf{u}\perp (AC)$$
$$\textbf{v}\perp (DEF)\iff \textbf{v}\perp (DE)\text{ and }\textbf{v}\perp (DF)$$
What's a way to construct a non-zero vector that's orthogonal to both $(AB)$ and $(AC)$? The answer is that you can take
$$\textbf{u}=\overrightarrow{AB}\times\overrightarrow{AC}$$
where $\times$ denotes the cross product of vectors and similarly
$$\textbf{v}=\overrightarrow{DE}\times\overrightarrow{DF}.$$
So a characterization of the sort that you ask is that
$$(ABC)\perp (DEF)\iff \left(\overrightarrow{AB}\times\overrightarrow{AC}\right)\cdot\left(\overrightarrow{DE}\times\overrightarrow{DF}\right)=0.$$
You might want to express this relationship in terms of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,f_2,f_3$.